# Umbraco 6 on iis6 issues with razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I have a bit of code in a razor .cshtml in a macroScript

its just getting a image from the image ID, like this:

```
<img src='@Library.MediaById(page.GetProperty("mainImage").Value).umbracoFile' alt='' />
```

It works perfectly fine on my local site, running in VS2010 inbuilt server, however when I move the site to a staging server running running iis6, it gives me the error:

```
Error loading MacroEngine script (file: article.cshtml)
```

Im using a compact database (umbraco.sdf) and the rest of the database driven content is working correctly, so Im stumped as to why this would work on local but not iis6.

The app pool is 4.0. and I couldnt find anything on umbraco site to suggest that iis6 isnt compatable.

Any ideas anyone?

EDIT: sorry its umbraco 6.06

tried adding ?umbdebugshowtrace=true to the url, no more info was given on the error

Comment: Try surrounding the code in a try/catch and then outputting the error in the catch, does that shed any light?

Comment: Thanks @DouglasLudlow, managed to locate the error after your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive Thanks to @Douglas Ludlow on this one. Seems stupid now that I didnt use a try to echo a error message.

The error was down to permissions and thanks to a post on the umbraco forum, it was down to a indexing issue.

The answer was to delete the contents of the TEMP child folders in the app_data directory.

Thanks to Dan Diplo on the forum for that one. Added the image here if anyone stumbles upon it in the future

(Most likly reason was a mix of the indexes not being correct even though pages where showing as published, and using ftp to deploy the site to the staging server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of umbraco is this?

Try and add ?umbdebugshowtrace=true to your url to get some more info on your error